# Why do you need the + between variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Why does this line work

```
$('#body-image').css("background-image", 'url('+ backgroundimage +')');
```

but not this one

```
$('#body-image').css("background-image", 'url('backgroundimage')');
```

or this one

```
$('#body-image').css("background-image", 'url(backgroundimage)');
```

Comment: This is not related to jQuery, but just to basic JavaScript (so jQuery in tag and title is inappropriate). It's in this particular case the string concatenation operator.

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting that SO provides. It's pretty telling.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I think I get it. You have to concatenate the variable into an existing string even though its undefined. Makes sense, and yeah I understand why the last example doesn't work now. Very helpful comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`backgroundimage` is a JavaScript variable. The concatenation operator in JavaScript is +, so to put a string together with a variable, you do `'some string ' + someVariable`. Without the +'s, JavaScript wouldn't know what to do with your variable (and in your third example, wouldn't even know that it *was* a variable).

Answer (score 2):

You need to concat the string with the variable `backgroundimage`. So you use "+" for this.

That's why this doesn't work.

```
$('#body-image').css("background-image", 'url('backgroundimage')');
```

And the secont doesn't work because there is no image called 'backgroundimage'.

```
$('#body-image').css("background-image", 'url(backgroundimage)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are building a string.  You are missing the line where backgroundimage gets a value:

```
 var backgroundimage = "someimage.gif";
 $('#body-image').css("background-image", 'url('+ backgroundimage +')');
```

becomes:

```
 $('#body-image').css("background-image", 'url(someimage.gif)');
```

Answer (score 0):

it's concatenating the string. 
let's say backgroundimage is 'foo.jpg, then

```
'url('+backgroundimage+')'  =  'url(foo.jpg)'
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, a string literal (i.e., "I am a string") is actually treated like a String object (though, strictly speaking, it isn't - see the [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) - but we can ignore the difference at this level). The following two lines are equivalent:

```
var letters = "ABC", numbers = "123";
var letters = new String("ABC"), numbers = new String("123");
```

Strings are concatenated using either the + operator or the String.concat method, either of which join 2 or more strings in a left-to-right order and return the result. So in order to get "ABC123", we can do any of the following:

```
"ABC" + "123"
"ABC" + numbers
letters + "123"
letters + numbers
"ABC".concat("123")
"ABC".concat(numbers)
letters.concat("123")
letters.concat(numbers)
```

but not:

```
letters"123"
"ABC"numbers
lettersnumbers
"lettersnumbers"
```

which are all, effectively, the same thing that you were trying to do in your examples.